# Change Highlighted Textbox to transparent borderbrush C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, border

Okay. I have tried almost every solution here in StackOverflow and still I cannot find the answer. This is what I want it to look like versus what it looks like. I cheated the textbox by doing this:

```
<Border Margin="100,20,100,20" BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" Background="#F7F7F7" BorderBrush="#CAC9CC" Height="32">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockUsername" Text="username" Margin="10,5,0,0" FontWeight="Light"/>
                <TextBox Margin="8,5,8,5" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" TextChanged="TextBoxUsername_TextChanged" SelectionBrush="Transparent"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

But apparently that Selection Border Brush just destroys the illusion. Any ideas on how to make it transparent?

Here are some photos:
[image: Normal]
[image: Selected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `BorderThickness="0"` for your TextBox:

```
<TextBox Margin="8,5,8,5" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TextChanged="TextBoxUsername_TextChanged" />
```

Comment: Thank you! This was it! I thought I had to go through SolidColorBrush or something. I didn't know it was THIS simple!